# apply no filter to an input

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm a beginner in python and started to learn a couple of weeks ago

I'm trying to write a code where the user chooses a month, and based on the input the relevant data will appear, however there's a stipulation that if the user typed **all** no filter should apply and all data should appear. what code help me with this?
this what I did.. any tips is much appreciated

```
months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun']
month = input('Please select the month you want to filter by, type all to apply no filter\nNote that we currently have data for the first 6 months only\nNote that you need to type only the first 3 letters of the month in lowercase e.g. (jan, feb, mar,...etc.')
while month not in months:
    month = input('{} isn\'t a valid month, Please enter a valid month'.format(month))
```

Comment: `while month not in months or month != 'all':` would probably do the trick.

Comment: @JNevill I think you want and, not or!

Comment: Oh yes. You are right. `and` not `or`. I've been doing this for years and that `<not> and/or <not>` pattern still throws me. `while month not in months and month != 'all':`